# Pass Category's attribute in url and display its sub categories

Tags: magento-1.9

**Background** :

I am displaying **sub-categories** of **category** in Json format once we pass category id in url....

[image]

**example** : [sitename.com/script.php?**category_id=2**](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/cat12.php?category_id=2)

[image]

**Note** : I created these categories using [Ultimate Module Creator custom module](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/)

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$cat_model = Mage::getModel('ultimate_mars/category');
$reqCat = (int)$_REQUEST['category_id'];

if ($reqCat > 0)
{
$_cate = $cat_model->getTreeModel()->getCollection()->addFilter("parent_id", $reqCat);
}
else 
{
$_cate = $cat_model->getTreeModel()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array('gt' => 1));
}

$category = array();
foreach ($_cate as $_category) {
    $category[] = array("name" => $_category->getCategoryname(), "id" => $_category->getEntityId());
}

echo json_encode($category);
```

**Requirement** :

Now instead of Category_id , i want to pass Attribute **Product Type** ( `producttype` is attribute code ) & get the same result....

[image]

so i replaced this line in above code :

```
$reqCat = (int)$_REQUEST['$attributeCode'];
```

**Issue** :

Than i tried to access with **[sitename.com/script.php?attributeCode=T_SHIRT](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/cat12.php?attributeCode=T_SHIRT)** , but its displaying all categories & sub categories :

[image]

app/code/local/Ultimate/Mars/Model/Category - **Source.php**

```
<?php

class Ultimate_Mars_Model_Category_Source extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{

    public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = false)
    {
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = Mage::getResourceModel('ultimate_mars/category_collection')

            ->load()
            ->toOptionArray();
        }
        $options = $this->_options;
        if ($withEmpty) {
            array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>''));
        }
        return $options;
    }


    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions(false);
        foreach ($options as $item) {
            if ($item['value'] == $value) {
                return $item['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getAllOptions();
    }


    public function getFlatColums()
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        $column = array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'default'   => null,
            'extra'     => null
        );
        if (Mage::helper('core')->useDbCompatibleMode()) {
            $column['type']     = 'int';
            $column['is_null']  = true;
        } else {
            $column['type']     = Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER;
            $column['nullable'] = true;
            $column['comment']  = $attributeCode . ' Category column';
        }
        return array($attributeCode => $column);
    }


    public function getFlatUpdateSelect($store)
    {
        return Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')
            ->getFlatUpdateSelect($this->getAttribute(), $store, false);
    }
}
```

[Here is link to Download module](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1em4p6d2FJyu8mQ7GQDlHlwIUtDwReAvc) : [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1em4p6d2FJyu8mQ7GQDlHlwIUtDwReAvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code & you need to add unique category code

replace url argument like $attributeCode to attributeCode

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$yourCategory = Mage::getModel('ultimate_mars/category');
if(isset($_REQUEST["attributeCode"])){
    $categryCode = $_REQUEST["attributeCode"]; /* Your requested category code */
    $yourCategory = $yourCategory->load($categryCode,"producttype");
}
else{
    $yourCategory = $yourCategory->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("parent_id",1)->getFirstItem();    
}
/* Getting subcategory of requested category code */
$cat_model = Mage::getModel('ultimate_mars/category');
$_categories = $cat_model->getTreeModel()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("parent_id",$yourCategory->getId());

$category = array();
foreach($_categories as $_category)
{
    $category[] = array("name" => $_category->getCategoryname(), "id" => $_category->getEntityId());
}

echo json_encode($category);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried your code in   [link1](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/cat11.php?attributeCode=T_SHIRT) , it gave same result as i said before in other post..... if you check code i posted in question & i got result as [link2](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/cat12.php?category_id=2) means if i pass `category_id=2` in url, than i am getting proper results, but when i pass attribute code, than its not working as [link3](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/cat12.php?attributeCode=T_SHIRT)..... can you please check code in question and give me updated code according to that.....

Comment: This is gold , this worked fine as [link](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/cat13.php?attributeCode=T_SHIRT)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do change like this.

Make request URL like this :

```
sitename.com/script.php?attributeCode=T_SHIRT
```

Then you can access value like this.

```
$reqAttribute = (int)$_REQUEST['attributeCode'];
```

Then you need to do your code with the use of this.

Comment: Thanks for answer, we don't want to pass `category_id` in url, we want to pass only `attributeCode` , please help me for this.....

Comment: I update answer, kindly check that.

Comment: tried updated code, still same result , please check code :  https://pastebin.com/9QJY1Khr

Comment: you need to change into your code, so it will give you sub caegory collection based on attribute value, that part is missing into your code. So do that.

Comment: Thanks for your time.... i got solution from other answer....